Source of the given Ganesha mantra
I have a Ganesha stotra from the website stotra Nidhi: https://stotranidhi.com/en/sri-vidya-ganesha-ashtottara-shatanamavali-in-english/
Which hindu texts or Upanishads provide the above mentioned stotra and which sage  is the author of this stotra?
